# How to make curl command into php?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I have this curl command

```
curl -L -O -o ' .$path.' -J "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id='.$id.'"
```

How would I transform this into php curl request keeping in mind all the flags. what are the equivalents in php

Here is what I have so far

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id='.$id.'");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

Comment: What is the issue with what you got? You've already covered the `-L` flag by setting `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`. The other flags are quite irrelevant since they are letting curl know what to do with the response (save it to file etc), which you don't do in PHP. Just take the result and do what you want with it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mainly the save action (-o $path) is missing:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id='.$id.'");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

file_put_contents($path, $result);
?>
```

Comment: What about the flag for redirection, when I retrieve the file its says 404, I just need to understand the php equivalent for those exact flags

Comment: 404 = not found. Redirection http headers are in the 300 range

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=123"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Why are you using the URL as a key for `$_ENV`?

Comment: so how do I move that file to another location after upload?

Comment: is the resulting file inside $result variable?

Comment: you can move it using file_put_contents. result will be in $result

Comment: Is it wise to have curl ignore the certificate? That should be the last option if all other tries to retrieve your url fail because of the cert. settings